# When does the circle ci workflow run?

Tags: github, circleci

I work with github and circle ci.

Is the workflow of circle ci executed when a pull request is made?

Or will it be executed when merged?

In the latter case, what if I want to test when pull request?

I think it will be executed when merged.

But why is it displayed as below when creating a pull request?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But why is it displayed as below when creating a pull request?

The article "[Setting up continuous integration with GitHub](https://circleci.com/blog/setting-up-continuous-integration-with-github/)" from [Stanley Ndagi](https://github.com/NdagiStanley) ([twitter](https://twitter.com/NdagiStanley)) points out to:

> Click the settings cog next to the repo name:
>
> In Advanced Settings, notice that `Only build pull requests` is turned off.
> **This means that every push to GitHub will run on CircleCI, including PRs**.